# Android APK includes native libraries but they are not installed

Tags: android, android-10.0

When I build my Android application, I end up with 3 binaries in my APK for each architecture and I have `android:extractNativeLibs="true"` defined in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file. When I install the application I expect the binaries to end up in `/data/app/my.app-base64==/lib/arm64` but instead:

- If I install using IntelliJ `run` it works correctly.
- Using `adb install my.apk` I get **1** of the binaries installed.
- Installing from Google Play Store, none of the binaries are installed.

Can anyone help? I thought the issue was that the binaries were not called `.so` but it seems that even when they are, it doesn't help. I've also tried splitting the application into the different abi parts which works correctly but the install has the same problem.

Comment: Do you use App Bundle for your app?

Comment: are you using bundle tools to break apart your aab file into multiple apk and then install.

Comment: I've tried with and without App Bundle. I'm not using any tools apart from Google Play Store to install from AAB when I tried that method.

Comment: Have you add the line like that: ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64' } in your app/build.gradle ?

Comment: Yes @easy_breezy and it made no difference :-(

Comment: @mjaggard Did the solution specified below help you? Thanks

Comment: @Flot2011 I'm afraid between then and now I've moved on so no longer trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**2022-07-10**

If you are using newer version of the `Gradle plugin 4.0+`, you may face issues when
your executable not being packaged into apk or extracted in.

`/data/app/package/lib/.../...`

There is a dirty trick for the Android Gradle plugin.

---

`Solution:`

**1. Create a folder structure in your file explorer** `lib/armeabi/executable` *(I use armeabi just as an example, it can be your architecture)*, also **`do not`** make it end with `.so`

**2. Now zip this `lib` folder and rename it to** `yournaming.jar`

**3. Copy and paste in your Android Studio** `libs` **directory**

[should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H5e4.png)

**4. Go to your `build.grade(app)`, in `dependencies` section add following line
for compiling** `.jar`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    ...
}
```

**5 Build your `.apk` and check with `analyze tool`, folder containing your `lib/armeabi/executable` should be now created in `.apk` itself.**

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a check if that fixes my problem. Does Google Play still remove this once built or can you then execute that file? My understanding eventually was that Google intentionally removed the ability to execute native executables that were included in the app.

Comment: Ye, I had the same thing in my head, that they removed it on purpose, but the thing is that even if you place a normal library and it is still not being extracted. I think it can be just some kind of bug. Try this method and let me know if it helped.